# Finding the mode of a function by MCMC sampling

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, optimization, monte-carlo

When trying to find the mode of a nonnegative function $f$ (i.e. maximize the function), one way to do it is to sampling the function viewed as an unnormalized density of some distribution via MCMC.

Suppose we have had a sufficiently long sequence of samples via this method, I was wondering how to determine the mode from the samples?

Specifically, as we know that a part taken from the end of the sequence will be assumed to be approximately subject to the distribution corresponding to the target function $f$. As far as I have thought already, there might be two choices for the estimation of the mode of the function:

1. take the last sample in the original sequence,
2. take a small subsequence from the end of the original sequence and evaluate the function f on every sample in the subsequence and pick the one with the maximal function value.

I saw the first choice from my class note, but the second was my first thought before looking at the note. So I was  wondering what choice for the mode of the target function might be reasonable or better and why? Possible to have any references on this? You don't have to limit your scope to the two I just mentioned.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode is indeed the maximum of f(x), so the value of x encountered during the simulation that gives the highest value of f(x) ought to be the best approximation of the mode.  AFAICS there is no good reason that the last sample should be the mode, unless you are performing simulated annealing and the temperature has fallen below the "freezing point" for the problem.  Likewise I don't see why only a small subset at the end of the run is important, the x maximising f(x) is the estimate of the mode regardless of where in the run it occurrs.

Comment: If (1) is mentioned in the lecture notes, it suggests that simulated annealing is the answer to your previous question on minimization of a function by Metropolis-Hastings algorithm as (1) would only be the mode for simulated annealing.

Comment: The purpose of only considering the tail subsequence of the original samples is because there is time needed to wait for the instrumental markov chain to have its distribution converge to its stationary distribution, whose density has been designed to be the target function.

Comment: In the class note, the first choice was not just mentioned for simulated annealing, but also for Metropolitan-Hastings algorithms.

Comment: After the chain has reached its stationary distribution, it will still be sampling from that distribution, so all you can say about the last sample is that it will be a sample from that distribution.  Of course the mode is the most probable value, but that doesn't even imply that the last sample is probably the mode!

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, your opinion is to evaluate the function on every sample after the MC has been seen as reaching its stationary distribution.

Comment: I would have thought that any sample, even before the burn in period is complete would be the mode (as it is only the maximum of f(x) that you seek).  However I could be wrong, but samples taken after reaching the stationary distribution would be fine, provided you had a sufficient number to be confident of adequately exploring the distribution. I suggest you speak to your instructor about the last sample issue as it seems there is some uncertainty about it.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will ask him. I now see your point to consider the samples before reaching stationary distribution.

Comment: @Tim Please, Metropolis; this has nothing to do with cities, guy had just strange surname. Back to the topic -- if you degenerate MH to simple accept-only-if-better (very small T), with some luck at the end you'll get $x$ just sitting in the global minimum.

Comment: @mbq: my mistake. By "degenerate MH to simple accept-only-if-better", do you mean at each iteration evaluate the function immediately when a new sample is generated and compare to the previous best? Also why choose "very small T", I assume T is fixed at some value, and if T is small, chance of getting stuck in a local minimum will be great, is it?

Comment: @Tim Yes -- this is sadly quite common. About getting stuck -- there is one more issue. Here we talk nothing about the next step generation, yet obviously making big steps can be a way to escape local minima (tunneling in physical termin.). Those are of course pathologies, but sometimes people use them "because they work".